# firefox window innerheight not updating on zoom

Tags: javascript, android, css, html, firefox

I'm implementing a html/css/js centered overlay that stays centered even when users are zooming in and out on the page.

The current implementation is centering the overlay based on the viewport width and height - determined by the window.innerWidht/Hegiht - in iOs Chrome, iOs Safari, Default Android, and Android Chrome.

Firefox however does not change the innerWidth and innerHeight of the window when zooming in or out. How can I determine the zoomed in/out viewport size in android firefox?

```
 overlay.css({
    "top" : metrics.documentBodyScrollTop,
    "left" : metrics.documentBodyScrollLeft,
    //the two lines below will never change on firefox mobile. WHY!?
    "max-width" : metrics.windowInnerWidth,
    "max-height" : metrics.windowInnerHeight
});
```

example to test is here : http://jsfiddle.net/agilius/L2EsH/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of a bug in Firefox that has now been fixed. If you try it with nightly build "27.0a1 (2013-10-03)" or later it will work.

You can find here [nightly.mozilla.org](http://nightly.mozilla.org/)

Comment: I was wondering if this is something that has to do with inconsistent CSS specification or a firefox problem. This is very good news. Thank you!